# How to fetch PDF (doc, docx) with Fetch API?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

There is another of doing this except the following code ?

```
fetch(url)
.then(response => response.blob())
.then(blob => console.log(blob))
```

Comment: What are you looking for exactly? What's wrong with that approach?